# how to load images dynamically when page loaded in jquery asp.net c#

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I want to preface this with the fact that I am very very new to JavaScript and jquery. I appreciate your patience with me.

I want to load an image dynamically using jquey (when the page is loaded) I have created a structure like this and using jquery I want to assign values dynamically to `alt` , `title` ,
`src` to this  `img` tags.

```
<div>
 <ul>
<li>
 <a data-title="Call Long 1">
<em><img class="img-responsive" alt="" title="" src="" /></em>
<span>Image 1</span></a>
</li>
<li>
 <a data-title="Call Long 2">
<em><img class="img-responsive" alt="" title="" src="" /></em>
<span>Image 2</span></a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

**Edit**:
After I implement the given solution in my logic the each loop not worked and as per my knowledge I have tried some different ways but those loops not are worked well suggest me how to achieve this.

Loops not working....

```
function LoadImages() {


    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        //url is the path of our web method (Page name/function name)
        url: "AutoTrade.aspx/LoadServiceImages",
        data: "{}",
        dataType: "json",
        //called on jquery ajax call success
        success: function (result) {

            $.each(result.d, function (key, value) {

                //$(".img-responsive").each(function () {
                //    $(this).attr('src', value.ImageURL).attr('title', value.Toltip).attr('alt', value.StrategyName);
                //});

                 $(".img-responsive").attr('src', value.ImageURL).attr('title', value.Toltip).attr('alt', value.StrategyName);

            });


            //$(".img-responsive").each(result.d, function (key, value) {

            //    $(this).attr('src', value.ImageURL).attr('title', value.Toltip).attr('alt', value.StrategyName);

            //});


            //for (var imgcount = 0; imgcount < result.d.length; imgcount++) {

            //    //alert('hit');
            //    //alert(result.d[i].Toltip)
            //    $(".img-responsive").attr('src', result.d[imgcount].ImageURL).attr('title', result.d[imgcount].Toltip).attr('alt', result.d[imgcount].StrategyName);
            //}



            //$(".img-responsive").each(result.d, function (key, value) {

            //    //alert(value.Toltip);

            //    $(".img-responsive").attr('src', value.ImageURL).attr('title', value.Toltip).attr('alt', value.StrategyName);

            //    //alert(value.Toltip);
            //});



            //$(".img-responsive").each(result.d, function () {

            //    //alert(value.Toltip);

            //    $(".img-responsive").attr('src', result.d[0].ImageURL).attr('title', result.d[0].Toltip).attr('alt', result.d[0].StrategyName);

            //    //alert(value.Toltip);
            //});




            //alert(result.d.length);
            //$(document).ready(function () {

            //    for (var i = 0; i < result.d.length; i++) {

            //        alert(value.Toltip);
            //        $(".img-responsive").attr('src', result.d[i].ImageURL).attr('title', result.d[i].Toltip).attr('alt', result.d[i].StrategyName);
            //        alert(value.Toltip);
            //    }

            //});


        },

        //called on jquery ajax call failure
        error: function ajaxError(result) {
            alert(result.status + ' : ' + result.statusText);
        }
    });

}
```

I'm sure that my inexperience with Javascript and jquery is the main cause of my being unable to figure this out. The script above is as far as I can get without screwing things up. Any help is appreciated.

Suggest me how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **[$( document ).ready()](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)** for this

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".img-responsive").each(function() {
            $(this).attr('src', 'image source');
            $(this).attr('title', 'image title');
            $(this).attr('alt', 'image alt text');
        });    
    });
```

Or you can call this code on any event

```
$(".img-responsive").each(function() {
    $(this).attr('src', 'image source').attr('title', 'image title').attr('alt', 'image alt text');
});
```

Please try this

```
function LoadImages() {
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    //url is the path of our web method (Page name/function name)
    url: "AutoTrade.aspx/LoadServiceImages",
    data: "{}",
    dataType: "json",
    //called on jquery ajax call success
    success: function(result) {
        var i = 0;
        $.each(result.d, function(key, value) {
            if (i < imgArry.length) {
                var img = imgArry[i];
                img.attr('src', value.ImageURL).attr('title', value.Toltip).attr('alt', value.StrategyName);
            }
            i = i++;
        });
    },
    //called on jquery ajax call failure
    error: function ajaxError(result) {
        alert(result.status + ' : ' + result.statusText);
    }

});
}
```

Comment: doc.ready isn't the answer as the code can just go at the end of body.  The answer is `$(this).attr` and `.each` (which you've included but not mentioned)

Comment: @Sain Pradeep thanks for your answer post and I have tryied your answer like this `$.each(result.d, function (key, value) {$(".img-responsive").attr('src', value.ImageURL).attr('title', value.Toltip).attr('alt', value.StrategyName);});` and I'm fetching this data using `ajax` call but while I'm looping and filling that data the last value of the index value only filling to each `li'` of image. why it is happing ? Am I did any mistake in looping ? Please guide me.

Comment: @freedomn-m please help me in looping.

Comment: @Kumar Please update your page full code to your question. So anyone can review and help you.

Comment: @SainPradeep thanks for your comment and I really appreciate your patience and I applied this code and did some modifications as per my requirements it is not working well and first I really not understand that code . I'm sorry for that